# jQuery get JSON access result

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm pulling a json array using the following command:

```
$.get('URL')
.always(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
```

The URL when accessed directly returns the following information:

```
{
    "user": {
        "ipaddr": "192.168.37.10.",
        "system_date": "Feb 10 10:38:51 PST 2015"
    },
    "clean_graph_allow": 0,
    "client": {
        "account_information": {
            0: {
                "ID": 7611,
                "accountID": "abcd",
                "label": "Billing",
                "email": "bob@jones.com",
                "firstName": "Bob",
                "lastName": "Jones",
                "company": "Bob inc.",
                "address": "123 Fake Street",
                "city": "Nowhere",
                "province": "CA",
                "postalCode": 91111,
                "country": "US",
                "phone": 5555555555,
                "notes": null,
                "company_type": null
            },
            1: {
                "ID": 7611,
                "accountID": "abcd",
                "label": "Billing",
                "email": "bob@jones.com",
                "firstName": "Bob",
                "lastName": "Jones",
                "company": "Bob inc.",
                "address": "123 Fake Street",
                "city": "Nowhere",
                "province": "CA",
                "postalCode": 91111,
                "country": "US",
                "phone": 5555555555,
                "notes": null,
                "company_type": null
            },
            2: {
                "ID": 7611,
                "accountID": "abcd",
                "label": "Billing",
                "email": "bob@jones.com",
                "firstName": "Bob",
                "lastName": "Jones",
                "company": "Bob inc.",
                "address": "123 Fake Street",
                "city": "Nowhere",
                "province": "CA",
                "postalCode": 91111,
                "country": "US",
                "phone": 5555555555,
                "notes": null,
                "company_type": null
            },
            "contact": {
                "ID": 7611,
                "accountID": "abcd",
                "label": "Billing",
                "email": "bob@jones.com",
                "firstName": "Bob",
                "lastName": "Jones",
                "company": "Bob inc.",
                "address": "123 Fake Street",
                "city": "Nowhere",
                "province": "CA",
                "postalCode": 91111,
                "country": "US",
                "phone": 5555555555,
                "notes": null,
                "company_type": null
            }
        },
        "is_reseller": 300
    },
    "hidden_pages": [],
    "action": "dashboard_api_stats",
    "attacks_today": 4920,
    "blocks": 1816,
    "short_blocks": 101,
    "nullroutes": 314,
    "num_countries": 0,
    "attack_dnsc": 3,
    "attack_pstc": 6,
    "attack_gc": 28,
    "attack_core": 55,
    "attack_tcpc": 8,
    "attack_udpc": 0,
    "regional": {
        "": 100
    }
}
```

The response I get back from the $.get or $.getJSON command that looks like this:

```
Object {
    readyState: 4,
    getResponseHeader: function,
        getAllResponseHeaders: function,
            setRequestHeader: function,
                overrideMimeType: function…
            }
            abort: function(a) {
                var b = a || u;
                return i && i.abort(b), x(0, b), this
            }
            always: function() {
                return e.done(arguments).fail(arguments), this
            }
            complete: function() {
                if (h) {
                    var d = h.length;
                    ! function f(b) {
                        m.each(b, function(b, c) {
                            var d = m.type(c);
                            "function" === d ? a.unique && k.has(c) || h.push(c) : c && c.length && "string" !== d && f(c)
                        })
                    }(arguments), b ? e = h.length : c && (g = d, j(c))
                }
                return this
            }
            done: function() {
                if (h) {
                    var d = h.length;
                    ! function f(b) {
                        m.each(b, function(b, c) {
                            var d = m.type(c);
                            "function" === d ? a.unique && k.has(c) || h.push(c) : c && c.length && "string" !== d && f(c)
                        })
                    }(arguments), b ? e = h.length : c && (g = d, j(c))
                }
                return this
            }
            error: function() {
                if (h) {
                    var d = h.length;
                    ! function f(b) {
                        m.each(b, function(b, c) {
                            var d = m.type(c);
                            "function" === d ? a.unique && k.has(c) || h.push(c) : c && c.length && "string" !== d && f(c)
                        })
                    }(arguments), b ? e = h.length : c && (g = d, j(c))
                }
                return this
            }
            fail: function() {
                if (h) {
                    var d = h.length;
                    ! function f(b) {
                        m.each(b, function(b, c) {
                            var d = m.type(c);
                            "function" === d ? a.unique && k.has(c) || h.push(c) : c && c.length && "string" !== d && f(c)
                        })
                    }(arguments), b ? e = h.length : c && (g = d, j(c))
                }
                return this
            }
            getAllResponseHeaders: function() {
                return 2 === t ? f : null
            }
            getResponseHeader: function(a) {
                var b;
                if (2 === t) {
                    if (!j) {
                        j = {};
                        while (b = Cc.exec(f)) j[b[1].toLowerCase()] = b[2]
                    }
                    b = j[a.toLowerCase()]
                }
                return null == b ? null : b
            }
            overrideMimeType: function(a) {
                return t || (k.mimeType = a), this
            }
            pipe: function() {
                var a = arguments;
                return m.Deferred(function(c) {
                    m.each(b, function(b, f) {
                        var g = m.isFunction(a[b]) && a[b];
                        e[f[1]](function() {
                            var a = g && g.apply(this, arguments);
                            a && m.isFunction(a.promise) ? a.promise().done(c.resolve).fail(c.reject).progress(c.notify) : c[f[0] + "With"](this === d ? c.promise() : this, g ? [a] : arguments)
                        })
                    }), a = null
                }).promise()
            }
            progress: function() {
                if (h) {
                    var d = h.length;
                    ! function f(b) {
                        m.each(b, function(b, c) {
                            var d = m.type(c);
                            "function" === d ? a.unique && k.has(c) || h.push(c) : c && c.length && "string" !== d && f(c)
                        })
                    }(arguments), b ? e = h.length : c && (g = d, j(c))
                }
                return this
            }
            promise: function(a) {
                return null != a ? m.extend(a, d) : d
            }
            readyState: 4 responseText: "{"
            user ":{"
            ipaddr ":"
            192.168.37.10.
            ","
            system_date ":"
            Feb 10 10: 38: 51 PST 2015 "},"
            clean_graph_allow ":0,"
            client ":{"
            account_information ":{0:{"
            ID ":7611,"
            accountID ":"
            abcd ","
            label ":"
            Billing ","
            email ":"
            bob@ jones.com ","
            firstName ":"
            Bob ","
            lastName ":"
            Jones ","
            company ":"
            Bob inc.
            ","
            address ":"
            123 Fake Street ","
            city ":"
            Nowhere ","
            province ":"
            CA ","
            postalCode ":91111,"
            country ":"
            US ","
            phone ":5555555555,"
            notes ":null,"
            company_type ":null},1:{"
            ID ":7611,"
            accountID ":"
            abcd ","
            label ":"
            Billing ","
            email ":"
            bob@ jones.com ","
            firstName ":"
            Bob ","
            lastName ":"
            Jones ","
            company ":"
            Bob inc.
            ","
            address ":"
            123 Fake Street ","
            city ":"
            Nowhere ","
            province ":"
            CA ","
            postalCode ":91111,"
            country ":"
            US ","
            phone ":5555555555,"
            notes ":null,"
            company_type ":null},2:{"
            ID ":7611,"
            accountID ":"
            abcd ","
            label ":"
            Billing ","
            email ":"
            bob@ jones.com ","
            firstName ":"
            Bob ","
            lastName ":"
            Jones ","
            company ":"
            Bob inc.
            ","
            address ":"
            123 Fake Street ","
            city ":"
            Nowhere ","
            province ":"
            CA ","
            postalCode ":91111,"
            country ":"
            US ","
            phone ":5555555555,"
            notes ":null,"
            company_type ":null},"
            contact ":{"
            ID ":7611,"
            accountID ":"
            abcd ","
            label ":"
            Billing ","
            email ":"
            bob@ jones.com ","
            firstName ":"
            Bob ","
            lastName ":"
            Jones ","
            company ":"
            Bob inc.
            ","
            address ":"
            123 Fake Street ","
            city ":"
            Nowhere ","
            province ":"
            CA ","
            postalCode ":91111,"
            country ":"
            US ","
            phone ":5555555555,"
            notes ":null,"
            company_type ":null}},"
            is_reseller ":300},"
            hidden_pages ":[],"
            action ":"
            dashboard_api_stats ","
            attacks_today ":4920,"
            blocks ":1816,"
            short_blocks ":101,"
            nullroutes ":314,"
            num_countries ":0,"
            attack_dnsc ":3,"
            attack_pstc ":6,"
            attack_gc ":28,"
            attack_core ":55,"
            attack_tcpc ":8,"
            attack_udpc ":0,"
            regional ":{"
            ":100}}"
            setRequestHeader: function(a, b) {
                var c = a.toLowerCase();
                return t || (a = s[c] = s[c] || a, r[a] = b), this
            }
            state: function() {
                return c
            }
            status: 200 statusCode: function(a) {
                var b;
                if (a)
                    if (2 > t)
                        for (b in a) q[b] = [q[b], a[b]];
                    else v.always(a[v.status]);
                return this
            }
            statusText: "OK"
            success: function() {
                if (h) {
                    var d = h.length;
                    ! function f(b) {
                        m.each(b, function(b, c) {
                            var d = m.type(c);
                            "function" === d ? a.unique && k.has(c) || h.push(c) : c && c.length && "string" !== d && f(c)
                        })
                    }(arguments), b ? e = h.length : c && (g = d, j(c))
                }
                return this
            }
            then: function() {
                var a = arguments;
                return m.Deferred(function(c) {
                    m.each(b, function(b, f) {
                        var g = m.isFunction(a[b]) && a[b];
                        e[f[1]](function() {
                            var a = g && g.apply(this, arguments);
                            a && m.isFunction(a.promise) ? a.promise().done(c.resolve).fail(c.reject).progress(c.notify) : c[f[0] + "With"](this === d ? c.promise() : this, g ? [a] : arguments)
                        })
                    }), a = null
                }).promise()
            }
            __proto__: Object
```

I apologize for the above formatting. I'm not sure how to properly format that.

Anyway, the important section of that is the responseText. responseText is equivalent to the data that is returned when the URL is directly accessed. I need to be able to pull specific elements from it (for example, attacks_today).

Something simple like:

```
data.responseText.attacks_today
OR
data['responseText']['attacks_today']
```

Do not work. I also tried various methods of looping, but they all give me the same type of error:

```
var arr = data.responseText;                                    
$.each( arr, function( index, entry ) {
```

Results in:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '1700' in ...
```

There's got to be some simple way to access json elements, unless I'm mistaken, but I'm just not seeing it.

I'm using jQuery version 1.11.0.

Thanks.

Comment: Matt: in every case that I tested (whether it be just trying to access the array element directly, or loop over the json array), get and getJSON have the same problem.

Comment: try `.then` instead of `.always`.

Comment: $.get('URL') or $.getJSON('URL')
.then(function(data) {
console.log(data); - this line displays nothing at all. data is empty.

Comment: Can you post an example of the JSON you are sending, and are you sending it with the correct content type i.e. application/json ?

Comment: Mac: under the network tab in chrome, it shows the following: Method: GET, Status: 200 OK, Type: application/json, Initiator: jquery.min.js:4 etc...

Comment: If you copy your JSON response into http://jsonlint.com, does it validate?

Comment: Mac: it sure doesn't - 
{
    "user": {
        "ipaddr": "69.197.63.142",
        "system_date": "Feb 10 11:11:47 PST 2015"
    },
    "clean_graph_allow": 0,
    "client": {
        "account_information": {
            0: {
                "ID": 7611,

It is erroring on the line that says "0: {" saying that it expects a string in place of the 0. Edit: shoot, it certainly doesn't format well here.

Comment: Try to parse data received from ajax, eg : data = JSON.parse(data) and this way you'll get an object instead of a string, talking about type of data

Comment: in JSON the field labels have to be in `""`. So `0: { "ID": 7611 ...` is not valid. It should be `"0": { "ID": 7611 ...`

Answer (score 1):

Your Ajax is failing.  The docs say the 1st parameter will be the xhr object or the data object if the request succeeded.

> jqXHR.always(function( data|jqXHR, textStatus, jqXHR|errorThrown ) {
>   });
>
> An alternative construct to the complete callback option, the
>   .always() method replaces the deprecated .complete() method.
>
> In response to a successful request, the function's arguments are the
>   same as those of .done(): data, textStatus, and the jqXHR object. For
>   failed requests the arguments are the same as those of .fail(): the
>   jqXHR object, textStatus, and errorThrown. Refer to deferred.always()
>   for implementation details.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

The object you are seeing is the XHR object because the request failed.  Use .done(data) if you want to make sure you always just get the result after you figure out why your request is failing.

Comment: Paul, yeah I actually realized it a couple of minutes ago after Mac pointed me in the direction of validating the JSON. .always works, but .done does not. .fail does so it's returning some bad data. I'll dig into why the data is bad. Thanks.

Comment: Make sure you are returning application/json in the response header.  That is the one thing I could think of that would break it if the URL you are passing to the request is correct and you are seeing a good response in the browser.

Comment: The response header was proper. The issue was that in other places in the code, completely separate from my work space, some extra data was being passed into the json return. Suppressing that extra stuff fixed the JSON validation, which fixed the issue. Thanks!